# CSS, Javascript and Images not loading in GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, github

My Portfolio loads perfectly fine when I open on my local machine, But when am trying to create a GitHub page non of the links works apart from the HTML.
I used the GitHub pages on different projects earlier, it works absolutely fine but it doesn't load here, can anyone help me out.
I tried various ways still it's the same.

Thank you

Here is my GitHub link https://github.com/Stellah-Avanthi/Portfolio-Project, I created a repo, But it doesn't seem to load on GitHub pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`Stellah-Avanthi/My-Personal-Profile-Page-`](https://github.com/Stellah-Avanthi/My-Personal-Profile-Page-) seems to work just fine (see [`stellah-avanthi.github.io/My-Personal-Profile-Page-`](https://stellah-avanthi.github.io/My-Personal-Profile-Page-/))
- while [`Stellah-Avanthi/Portfolio-Project`](https://github.com/Stellah-Avanthi/Portfolio-Project) does not (see [`stellah-avanthi.github.io/Portfolio-Project/`](https://stellah-avanthi.github.io/Portfolio-Project/))

In the second case, you are [referencing your css files](https://github.com/Stellah-Avanthi/Portfolio-Project/blob/06562942aaab08d26ab999b2e92ce1e5c703770c/index.html#L8-L9) as:

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

But you don't have a `css` folder in your repository.
So none of your stylesheet is loaded.

In the first site, [you are using](https://github.com/Stellah-Avanthi/My-Personal-Profile-Page-/blob/65e5fb5798777ba11f22d1887ed586ff8dd22a0f/index.html#L7)

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

That works just fine, considering `style.css` is right next your `index.html` file.